# Symfony3 custom Exception returning a JSON response

Tags: php, symfony, exception

I'd like to create a custom Exception on Symfony3 that returns a JSON response to be able to handle it in JavaScript afterwards.

Does someone know if it's possible and how to do it ?

Comment: You can simply return a `new Response(json_encode(...))` with the appropriate headers of course.

Comment: It's indeed what I did for the moment. But I'd really like to be able to make the difference in the code between a simple page returning a Json code and an exception returning a Json code...

Comment: You could handle that via an exception handler, a standard json response, an exception bubbling class(fancy word for exception handler class) and I'm sure there are other ways.

Comment: Return new JSONResponse if you don't whant to se the appropriate headers

Answer (score 2):

Create a new **exception handler class**, like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Subscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;

class ExceptionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /* ... */

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [ KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => 'onKernelException' ];
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $customResponse = new JsonResponse(['error' => 'My custom error message']);
        $event->setResponse($customResponse);
    }

}
```

Don't forget to register the new service in *app/config/services.yml*:

```
app.exception_subscriber:
    class: AppBundle\Subscriber\ExceptionSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```